# Link by id in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there any possibility to create a hash link in React JS?

A have for example something like this :

```
<div className="nav">
   <Link to="">Home</Link>
   <Link to="#services">Services</Link>
   <Link to="#contact">Contact</Link>
</div>
```

And if user clicks on services I want that he goes to the section of the page with the id `services`.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

App component code(main component) :

```
<div>
   <Header route={this.props.location.pathname}
           language={this.props.language.labels}
           authenticated={this.props.authenticated}
           signoutAction={this.props.actions}
   />
   {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
           currentLanguage: this.props.language.labels,
           authenticated: this.props.authenticated
    })}
    <Footer currentLanguage={this.props.language.labels}/>
</div>
```

Header component :

```
<ul className="noPadding">
     <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <a href="">Home </a></li>
     <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <a href="">Kenmerken </a></li>
     <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <a href="">Voordelen </a></li>
     <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, "whoAreWe")}>Wie zijn wij?</Link></li>
     <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <a href="#contact">Contact </a></li>
     <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <MainButton text="Aanmelden"/></li>
</ul>
```

Home component :

```
render(){
    const languageHome = this.props.currentLanguage.default.homePage;
    let loginBox = !this.props.authenticated ? (<div id="cta-1" className="onlyOnDesktop"><Login currentLanguage={languageHome}/></div>) : "";

    return (
        <div className="homeMain">
            <section className="marginOnXs" style={{width: '100%', padding: 0}}>
                <MainSlider />
            </section>

            <section className="why-us" style={{paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0}}>
                <Info currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
            </section>

            <div className="clearfix"></div>

            <section className="benefits noPadding">
                <Benefits currentLanguage={languageHome} />
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
            </section>

            <section ref="whoAreWe" id="whoAreWe" className="whoAreWe noPadding">
                <WhoAreWe currentLanguage={languageHome} />
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
```

All sections are in Home component and Home component renders in

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
       currentLanguage: this.props.language.labels,
       authenticated: this.props.authenticated
})}
```

Handle scroll function :

```
handleScroll(id, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const item = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[id]);
    window.scrollTo(item.offsetTop);
}
```

That what I see in console :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is create simple html links:

```
<div className="nav">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="#services">Services</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

And use jQuery for smooth scroll:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

You can also handle scrolling in onClick event:

```
<div className="nav">
    <Link onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, 'home')}>Home</Link>
    <Link onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, 'services')}>Services</Link>
    <Link onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, 'contact')}>Contact</Link>
</div>
```

And function:

```
handleScroll(id){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( '#' + id ).offset().top
    }, 500);        
}
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can add refs to components (home, services etc) and set window scrollTop to element position.

For example:

```
handleScroll(id){
    const item = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[id]);
    window.scrollTo(item.offsetTop);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the nav code and those section are not in the same file. And then `item ` is empty.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem properly... The menu and div's which are linked in the menu are rendered in a single page?

Comment: My solution with refs should work properly with the code you pasted